# Explain why at any fixed point in the SIR model should the number of infected individuals be equal to zero?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, fixed-point-theorems, numerical-calculus, fixed-points

[image]

Someone help me please, I have no idea how to solve this.

Comment: A fixed point of an iterative system of equations is a solution such that all variables remain fixed. That is, $S_n=S_f$, $I_n=I_f$, $R_n=R_f$ for all $n$. So to test for a fixed point, you'd substitute those values in the system and look for solutions. (Presumably you must assume $a>0,b>0$.) Evidently, the only value of $I_f$ that'll work is $I_f=0$.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand how the fixed points work and I see why the number of infected people should be equal to zero. But how can I prove this mathematically?

Comment: Try looking at the third equation. If $R_n$ can't change, what does this tell you about $bI_{n-1}$? (As I said, you do need to assume $b>0$. Otherwise, you'd have a disease where infected people never recover.)

Comment: thank you so much man you saved me. I managed to solve the system and prove that (I) n = 0